# long review comments partially hidden by freeze panes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to add a note to a column, to tell others the format of the column. I think it is a good idea to add a [review comment](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Annotate-a-worksheet-by-using-comments-bdcc9f5d-38e2-45b4-9a92-0b2b5c7bf6f8) to the column header, but this doesn't work with frozen first row: when I scroll down, the comment moves up with the sheet.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation, now I'm not using review comment for column notes. From [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8bbf5e0f-ba3a-437e-9528-a74e584faefa/excel-long-review-comments-partially-hidden-by-freeze-panes?forum=excel), we can add "Input Message" of [Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) property to all the cells in that column.

[image]

[image]

#### Caveat

"Input Message" doesn't allow one longer than 255 characters.